Covering interval by prescribed open sets.
Consider $I=[0,1]$. Assume a priori we are given a collection of open sets $(U_{t})_{t\in [0,1]}$, $U_t$ open in $I$ such that $I=\bigcup_{t\in I}U_t$. Here, $U_t\owns t$.
Problem is: Show that there exists $0=t_0<t_1<....<t_k=1$ such that $U_{t_i}\cap U_{t_{i+1}}\neq \varnothing$ for all $i$ and $I=\bigcup_{i=1}^kU_{t_i}$
My attempt:
Since $I$ is compact, find $w_1,w_2,...,w_n$ such that $I=\bigcup_{i=1}^nU_{w_i}$. Adjoin $U_0$ and $U_1$ if necessary so we may assume $w_0=0$ and $w_n=1$.
Set $t_0=w_0=0$. We must find $1>t_1>t_0$ such that $U_{t_1}\cap U_{t_0}\neq\varnothing$.
Since $U_{t_0}$ is open, there exists an $r>0$ such that $B_{r}(t_0)\subseteq U_{t_0}$. Fix any $t_1\in B_{r}(t_0)$ such that $1>t_1>t_0=0$. Then, $U_{t_1}\cap U_{t_0}\neq \varnothing$.
Can I ensure that there exists $1>t_2>t_1>t_0=0$ such that $U_{t_2}\cap U_{t_1}\neq \varnothing$. If it is so, then one can do induction.
I think one should implement the pigeonhole principle. Is there an easier way?

Is $N_t=U_t$?..

@Randall Oh my, yes sorry! edited!

Can we assume $t\in U_t$?

@4u9ust yup! :) (Included in edit)

That a finite number of these exist is the definition of compact, so the only thing you have to show is they are not (up to indexing) disjoint.  I think we can use that $[0,1]$ is connected.  So for any $t\in [0,1]$ so that $t\in U_{w_j}$ we can not have $[0,t)\cup(t,1]= \cup_{i\ne j}U_{i}$.  So there is another $U_{w_k}$ also containing $t$. so we can relabel $t$ and $U_{w_j}$ and $U_{w_k}$ as $t_h$, $U_{t_h}$ and $U_{t_{h+1}}$  and select $t_{h+1}$ as any point in $U_{w_k}$ that has not been used to index so far.

@fleablood I would appreciate it if you wrote it as an answer! :)

I think I'm a little short on detail.  And I wasn't actually positive it didn't have a glaring hole in it.  But okay... I'll work on getting it up there as an answer.

Your simple compactness argument is not sufficient. You might end with $t_0 = 0, t_1 = 1/2, t_2 = 3/4, t_3 = 1$ and $U_{t_0} = [0,1/4), U_{t_1} = (1/4,1), U_{t_2} = (1/8,7/8), U_{t_3} = (7/8,1]$ which does not satisfy your requirement. This cover is even irredducible; no three of these sets cover $I$.
I suggest to do it as follows. Call $x \in I$ accessible if there exists a tuple $(t_0,\ldots,t_k)$ such that

$0 = t_0 < t_1 < \ldots < t_k = x$
the $U_{t_i}$ cover $[0,x]$
$U_{t_i} \cap U_{t_{i+1}} \ne \emptyset$ for all $i$.

$0$ is clearly accesible via the one- element tuple $(t_0 =0)$. We want to show that $1$ is accessible.
Let $A$ denote the set of accessible $x$ and $\tau = \sup A$.

$\tau \in A$.

Assume that $\tau \notin A$. There exists $r > 0$ such that $(\tau - r,\tau + r) \cap I \subset U_\tau$. By definition  of $\tau$ there is an accessible $x \in (\tau -r,\tau)$. Let $(t_0, \ldots,t_k)$ an associated tuple for $x$. Then $(t_0, \ldots,t_k, t_{k+1} = \tau)$ is an associated tuple for $\tau$. Hence $\tau \in A$, a contradiction.

$\tau  = 1$.

Assume that $\tau < 1$. Let  $(t_0, \ldots,t_r)$ be an associated tuple for $\tau$. There exists $r > 0$ such that $(\tau - r,\tau + r) \cap I \subset U_\tau$. Pick $x \in (\tau,\tau+ r) \cap I$. Then $(t_0, \ldots,t_r, t_{r+1} = x)$ is an associated tuple for $x$. Hence $x \in A$, wich contradicts the definition  of $\tau$.

could you please perhaps also mention how you came up with this argument? It seems like 'magic' to me.

$\sup$-arguments are quite standard when one considers intervals. See for example here. The idea was this: If we have a sequence $t_0, \ldots, t_k$ covering some $[0,x]$, we can easily extend it as in step 2.
